# Exception while click on column of the grid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a datagrid and on cellClick event get data on the relevent texbox for editing.
When I click on the row it works fine but when I click on any of the column it gives exception and I dont know why.

Here's my code :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    itmId.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    itmNme.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    untCst.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    qntty.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    manfDate.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It appears that Ted Spence's answer helped you solve your problem. It it was the solution then you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on the header of the table, it sends the row index of -1.  There are other instances where this event can fire with invalid rowindex and columnindex values.

You should test rowindex and columnindex before using them.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0) {
        // .. my code goes here ..
    }
}
```

In some cases, you may also need to test whether the rowindex and columnindex go beyond the limits of the backing data.

Comment: I'm not familar with the dataGrid object. But typically 0 is a valid index.